# How do I execute the code for a timer control without activating the form that contains the timer in C#?

Tags: c#, timer

While running the project I open three forms, one of them contains the timers.

While I work on another form, the project activates the form that contains the timer, due to the timer code (e.g. play each 10 sec).

How can I modify the timer code in order to work without activating the timer form?

Here is the code that the timer should execute:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    btnRefresh.PerformClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have used the 'Form.Activated' event to run the timer control and also I have used another event 'Form.Deactivate' event to stop the timer.
Thank you and best regards**

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the timer public ans static. This will initialize the timer when the code is cimpiled and make it accessible through formname.timername

Another other option is to create a second in the other form